# Toggling elements order when switching views with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm working with a set of elements that has both a list view (default) and a grid view. I used an unordered list to fake the table view and so I would be able to switch to the grid view without having to create a different markup. (I want to avoid the use of absoluted positioned elements all over the place)

**List view**

```
<ul class="list">
<li class="header">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
    <p class="date">Start Date</p>
    <p class="title">Title</p>
</li>
<li class="even">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Adam Ant</h2>
    <p class="date">1995</p>
    <p class="title">Specialist</p>
</li>
<li class="odd">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Brian Box</h2>
    <p class="date">2005</p>
    <p class="title">Specialist</p>
</li>
<li class="even">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Clara Clock</h2>
    <p class="date">2010</p>
    <p class="title">Manager</p>
</li>
<li class="odd">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Darla Dock</h2>
    <p class="date">1996</p>
    <p class="title">Editor</p>
</li>
```

**Grid View**

```
<ul class="grid">
<li class="header">
   <p class="title">Title</p>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
    <p class="date">Start Date</p>

</li>
<li class="even">
   <p class="title">Specialist</p>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Adam Ant</h2>
    <p class="date">1995</p>

</li>
<li class="odd">
    <p class="title">Specialist</p>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Brian Box</h2>
    <p class="date">2005</p>

</li>
<li class="even">
    <p class="title">Manager</p>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Clara Clock</h2>
    <p class="date">2010</p>

</li>
<li class="odd">
<p class="title">Editor</p>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="name">Darla Dock</h2>
    <p class="date">1996</p>

</li>
```

The tricky part is that the order of the elements in the list view is different that in the grid view. So I used prependTo to target some elements and change the order once the view is switched to the grid view. It's working fine so far. The problem is that once the view is switched again back to the list view, the elements won't return to their original order.

I guess is easier to see with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDF7A/

This is is the javascript code I'm using to switch views and prepend the .title element so it shows before the .image element.

```
$('.controls a').bind('click', function(){
$('.controls a').toggleClass('active');
$('ul').toggleClass('list').toggleClass('grid');
$('ul.grid li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.title', $this).prependTo($this);
});
```

});

As you can see, the image element comes first in the list view and second in the grid view but once you try to switch back to the list view, the image stays in second place and won't return to the first place it should be. I know this is probably simple to achieve with jquery. I have only recently started to fiddle with it so I'm stuck here. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can appendTo if it has a list class like you are doing with the grid class. appendTo will place the title back on the end like it was to begin with.

Like this

```
$('ul.list li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.title', $this).appendTo($this); 
});
```

Here's the full code. And here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/ggQ9s/1/).

```
$('.controls a').bind('click', function(){
    $('.controls a').toggleClass('active');
    $('ul').toggleClass('list').toggleClass('grid');

    $('ul.grid li').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.title', $this).prependTo($this);
    });    

    $('ul.list li').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.title', $this).appendTo($this); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `prependTo` while switching to grid view , you must revert that change while switching back to list view. So you need to revert that change :

```
$('.controls a').bind('click', function(){
    $('.controls a').toggleClass('active');
    $('ul').toggleClass('list').toggleClass('grid');
    $('ul.grid li').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.title', $this).prependTo($this);
    });   
    $('ul.list li').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.image', $this).prependTo($this);
    });  
});
```

And here is the updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tDF7A/1/).